# Form tag is stripped off in Cake Php

Tags: forms, cakephp-1.3, form-helpers

Form tag is stripped off in Cake Php view file.

In 'login.ctp' (Layout view)

```
    <div id="test">

        <?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
             Test form Elements
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>

    </div>
```

When checked in firebug console only creating  below tags

```
    <div id="test">

        <div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></div>

        Test form Elements
    </div>



// "<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></div>". This div tag is  automatically created.
```

I also created a 'inner.ctp' on elements in  views and tried to call from layout view(login.ctp) as echo $this->element('inner') , but results in same problem

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost certain that you have another form on your page, probably in your layout, that you're not closing with...

```
echo $this->Form->end();
```

If this is not the case, I suggest getting the [latest stable version of Cake 1.3](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/1.3) and overwriting your current one.